# Do Linux devices require user permissions? If so, how are they added?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, permissions, centos

Trying to create a new virtual server using VirtualBox and phpVirtualBox on a physical Centos box.  Installed the software and all seems good.  Put the operating disk in the CD drive of the physical machine, but got the following error from phpVirtualBox:

> Cannot open host device '/dev/sr0' for readonly access. Check the
>   permissions of that device ('/bin/ls -l /dev/sr0'): Most probably you
>   need to be member of the device group. Make sure that you logout/login
>   after changing the group settings of the current user
>   (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Following the instructions, I see the following:

```
[root@desktop ~]# /bin/ls -l /dev/sr0
brw-rw----. 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Nov 18 10:30 /dev/sr0
```

I understand how Linux files have user permissions.  Do devices have something similar?  How are permissions on devices viewed and modified?

I found that group 11 is cdrom.  I've since added this group to my phpVirtualBox user, but still get the same error.

Don't think it matters, but the CD is Windows 7.

Please provide any recommendations.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)

That phrase is a classic adage in the Linux world and it is meant to be taken quite literally. In the Linux world, (almost) everything is a file. This includes [pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156), [directories](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Earik/usail/concepts/filesystems/everything-is-a-file.html) and [devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file). So, the way of changing permissions for a device is the same as doing so for any other file:

```
# ls -l /dev/sr0
brw-rw---T+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Nov 18 14:55 /dev/sr0
# chmod a+rw /dev/sr0
# ls -l /dev/sr0 
brw-rw-rwT+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Nov 18 14:55 /dev/sr0
```

You shouldn't need to do this though. Adding the correct user to the `cdrom` group shoujld be enough. You have not explained what users you have and who does what. I assume you are launching the VM with your normal user. Is that user in the group?

I assume the error you are receiving is the VM complaining that it cannot access the physical drive. This probably means that the user launching the VM is not in the `cdrom` group.

If this is what you've done and it doesn't work, please update your question and show exactly *how* you added *which* user to the group.

Comment: Thanks terdon,  I added just about every related user to the cdrom group.  Was this the one I should be adding it to?  That being said, your description of everything being a file was helpful, seemed to meet my immediate needs.  While I will select your response as the best answer, if you have any addition words of wisdom, please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 it looks like it, yes. I have never used the host drive with a VM though so there may be other permissions issues.  You could post a new question here or at [unix.se] focusing on how to install a VM using the host cd drive. Explain when exactly you get this message, which user you are running as etc.